# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in

Tags: php, arrays, popen

I'm trying to run a command that outputs when the results whenever something changes. However, I keep getting an `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, resource given in` error.

Here is my code:

```
$call = "~/www/reteps.tk/go/kahoot-auto " . '262671' . " " . 'bob' . " ";
$result = array();
$old_result = array(0 => "something");

$handle = popen($call, "r");
$result = file($handle); #is this how I read the results?
while (in_array("end",$result) != true) {
  sleep(1); 
  if ($result != $old_result) {
    echo($result);
    $old_result = $result;
  }   
}
```

Full Error log:

```
PHP Warning:  file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /home/retep/www/reteps.tk/school/kahoot2.php on line 70
PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/retep/www/reteps.tk/school/kahoot2.php on line 71
PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/retep/www/reteps.tk/school/kahoot2.php on line 71
PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/retep/www/reteps.tk/school/kahoot2.php on line 71
```

Comment: What about `$call`?

Comment: sorry, I added` $call` to my code. It's a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide the value of $call?  The error seems to indicate that it's a resource instead of a path.  popen() requires a $command:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php

So $call should be a string of some kind, either a Linux command or executable file path or something.  Right now $call appears to be a resource, so the path or command may be INSIDE of the resource and you just need to point to that value instead of the resource itself.

Comment: $handle = popen('/path/to/executable 2>&1', 'r');
echo "'$handle'; " . gettype($handle) . "\n";
$read = fread($handle, 2096);
echo $read;
pclose($handle);

Comment: So instead of using file(), use fread() as indicated in the code above - in there, the $read variable ends up with the whole result, which you can then parse as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the path of the file (may be `$call`) in the `file` function and you put a ressource (`$result`)

Answer (score 0):

Your path specified for file is not found by the system. Hence, $result doesn't gets any value. And in your next statement in array requires 2nd parameter to be array, but $result is not an array as path was not valid.

Your in array code is fine. Just check the path of the file. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

//my code

```
$r=array(10.5,11,45,78,85,90);

if(in_array(4,$r)) {
    echo "number is found";
} else {
    echo "number is not found";
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.